# Small square button in GTK+

Tags: c++, button, gtk

I need to populate GtkGrid with many buttons, but they are too large and cannot fit on the screen. How can I make it 10px * 10px? set_size_request does not work in this case.

```
   for(int i{0}; i < 128; i++){
        for(int j{0}; j < 8; j++){
            paint_btn_arr[i][j] = gtk_button_new();
        }
    }
    up_grid = gtk_grid_new();
    down_grid = gtk_grid_new();
    for(int i{0}; i < 64; i++){
        for(int j{0}; j < 8; j++){
            gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(up_grid), paint_btn_arr[i][j], i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    for(int i{0}; i < 64; i++){
        for(int j{0}; j < 8; j++){
            gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(down_grid), paint_btn_arr[i + 64][j], i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using Owner Drawn options?  You'll need to adjust the font size as well (if you are using fonts on your buttons).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Did you mean to use gtk_widget_set_size_allocate with grids? This method does not work.